# How to navigate to item details page from listitems page after clicking on listitem(using data binding) in windows phone 8

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone 8 development. I have gone through the video tutorials by Bob Taybor in MSDN website. I am working on an application which is used to maintain the expenses.
I have created 3 viewmodel classes and storing the data in the isolated storage in the json format.

On opening the expense page in the application there will be list of items. I have written a logic which can store the expenses and shows in the expencesview. I got struck up near populating(navigating to) item details page of the listitem clicked(using Data Binding.

I don't know how to bind that specific object to XAML in the items details page(update expenses page in my project). I also want to update and save the model if the user changes the input.

It would be so helpful if someone can implement this flow. Hopefully someone would have worked on the same requirement. I have shared the code in the below link. I have gone through few tutorials, on NotifyPropertyChanged etc..,but still have many doubts.

It will be so helpful for beginners to understand the concepts well with some real time example. I want to share this as an example after completion.

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=83F2A501543779D4%211222

Looking forward for help,
Thank Y

Comment: You should show what you have done by now

Comment: It got data populated. On navigating to next page I have set the datacontext. I am working on updating that data. Can anyone suggest as to how to proceed on this.                                         if(data != null)
                this.DataContext = data.Expences[Convert.ToInt32(selectedIndex)];